# A powerfully, powerfully, powerfully written number sequence

Tags: number-sequence, english

Find the missing terms a<sub>17</sub> , a<sub>19</sub> and a<sub>22</sub> of the sequence,

> 15 , 20 , 13 , 2 , 20 , 17 , 17 , 19 , 19 , 15 , 14 , 4 , 21 , 4 , 20 , 17 , a<sub>17</sub> , 19 , a<sub>19</sub> , 15 , 14 , a<sub>22</sub>

The sequence uses only basic Mathematics and less common English.

Comment: curious why you removed the last term?

Comment: Good spot - it was incorrect - you may see why from a certain table . The sequence can  be extended indefinitely (and I believe uniquely using a convention given by two English mathematicians). The  earlier terms in the sequence should, I hope, be enough to identify it, after using the applied tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values are

> a<sub>17</sub> = 17, a<sub>19</sub> = 19, a<sub>22</sub> = 22

The sequence might be easier to see if we first

> Use A1Z26 to convert all elements to letters: 
>  o , t , m , b , t , q , q , s , s , o , n , d , u , d , t , q , ? , s , ? , o , n , ?

Which can then be seen to mean:

> The powers of one thousand: one, thousand, million, billion, trillion, quadrillion, quintillion, ...
>
>  The missing elements are Quinquadecillion, Septendecillion and Vigintillion, which converted back to numbers are 17, 19 and 22 respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The values are:

> a<sub>17</sub> = 17, a<sub>19</sub> = 19, a<sub>22</sub> = 4

This is because...

> there is a loop in the graph. Notice how points 5 to 12 are a complete version of points 15 to 22. [image: Graph describing explanation]

Comment: i don't think that's going to be the answer

Comment: Could you give some follow up to your statement? I'm not disagreeing with you, but would like your reasoning.

Comment: i was working on an interpolated polynomial

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea.

Comment: ... or a Fourier series?